# Editing a bound textbox does not immediately reflect changes in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am editing a datagridview that has its datasource set to a binding source, which has its datasource set to a datatable.

In addition, I am using a bound textbox to edit information displayed on the datagridview. The problem that I am running into is that when I edit the textbox, the changes are not displayed on the datagridview unless I click to another row. I have tried some solutions (below), but the ones that work seem to reset my I-beam textbox cursor position to the beginning.

I'm trying to have

1. Any changes that I make commit immediately
2. The datagridview update as I'm typing into the textbox.

I know that this question has been asked to death - I have tried the below solutions:
1.

```
private void datagridview1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (datagridview1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        datagridview1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

2.
This one works, but the application moves my I-beam to the beginning of the textbox. Frustrating when I'm trying to add characters to the middle of a string.

```
private void Textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bindingsource1.EndEdit();
}
```

3.
Same issue as above. This one works, but the application moves my I-beam to the beginning of the textbox. Frustrating when I'm trying to add characters to the middle of a string.

```
private void datagridview1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    datagridview1.BindingContext[datagridview1.DataSource].EndCurrentEdit();

}
```

None of the above is working. Please help!

Comment: Option 2, but using the LostFocus or Leave event of the TextBox?

Comment: yes, I know. My suggestion is to try those events instead.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to have (1) any changes that I make commit immediately and (2) the datagridview update immediately as I'm typing into the textbox. Unfortunately, I LostFocus or Leave events would require me to click out of the textbox, which I don't want to do.

Comment: Just calling `bindingsource1.EndEdit();` in the `TextChanged` event does not change the cursor's position. See what methods are you calling ahead in your code. For example, because you are calling `(bindingsource1.DataSource as DataTable).AcceptChanges();`. Or, the TextBox in some unusual how loses then regains the focus.

Comment: I can recreate the issue you describe about the cursor moving to the first position after you click into the text box and type a character. And I wish I had a good answer/solution. However, I have to ask… if you are going to all this trouble such that if the user types characters into the grid cell or a `TextBox` with the same string value, i.e. … both the grid cell and the text box “always” contain the same value… then would it not be easier and more user friendly to simply allow the user to “edit” the grid cell directly and drop the external `TextBox` all together?

Comment: I am just saying that “duplicating” data in the form indicates a poor UI choice. It makes more work for you and it is not going to help the user. If some of the data is not shown in the grid… then the external `TextBox` make sense to allow the user to edit those values that are not displayed in the grid. But, allowing the user to edit two (2) different controls (grid and text box) to edit data in the grid is… well… awkward. And as mentioned already, this creates extra work and problems for you as your question validates.

Comment: Keeping the two controls in an absolute synced state is not as trivial as it may appear and my point is “why” duplicate the data on the form and create more work for yourself? Simply let the user “edit” the cells directly in the grid. Sorry if I am missing something.